# Grant permissions via voice input

Tags: android, android-permissions, voice-recognition

Since Android 6 permissions can be requested on runtime. The user has the chance to grant or revoke permissions. He is always asked by the UI in form of a dialog popping up.

Is it somehow possible to grant permissions via voice input? I searched by myself but didn't find any approach for that. Is there any information to find about this topic? At least maybe some research how to make that possible maybe in future Android versions?

It would be great to find any kind of useful information about. that topic

Comment: HAHA - Accessing the microphone (to capture voice input for example) itself requires runtime permission. Talk about a catch-22...

Comment: Sure it does but we could imagine to grant microphone permission on first launch and then request the other permissions via voice.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so. It would not be safe, the user could accuse the application after capturing his audio without permission, for example.

You must EXPLICITLY allow anything (even acess the microphone to capture anything) that involves application access. So it's complicated for you to define something as explicit when using voice. The user may claim that he was only in a normal conversation when the application was granted permissions, and this can cause problems ...